# Rotate a Video 90 degrees

Tags: video-editing, rotate

I have a camera that records video. We thought it would auto-sense that it was sideways, but if it had... I wouldn't be here.

Windows comes with Movie Maker, that does this... but it saves the file as a Movie Maker Format that isn't compatible with anything else and is a bit more involved than I'd like it to be (needs to be done for many videos, so simple is needed).

What are some good options to rotate a video 90 degrees on Windows?

Edit: I've found [this](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-Video-Flip-and-Rotate.htm) that is simple and works. Mov in, mov out... it does seem to down-convert the files though (files are about 1/3rd the size, although the differences aren't real noticeable by me). I'd almost want a few more options, like the ability to control the changes in the output file. Maybe choose a different format (MOV to WMV or what have you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [X-WinFF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winpenpack/files/X-WinFF/) (FFmpeg GUI) with [`-vf "transpose=x"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937387/rotating-videos-with-ffmpeg/9570992#9570992) command to batch transpose videos.
<sup>On older FFmpeg builds the syntax for that command differs and needs to be adjusted</sup>

Possible parameters for x are:

```
0 = 90° CounterCLockwise and Vertical Flip (default)
1 = 90° Clockwise
2 = 90° CounterClockwise
3 = 90° Clockwise and Vertical Flip
```

The screenshot below shows where to enter the additional transpose command.
I've done a quick test and it works. You could also re-encode the video as you wished.

[image]

---

Maybe you want to "rotate" the aspect ratio too. Just add `-aspect x:y` to the command-line

Example to rotate a 16:9 aspect ratio video

```
-vf "transpose=1" -aspect 9:16
```

Example to rotate a 4:3 aspect ratio video

```
-vf "transpose=1" -aspect 3:4
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do 180 degree flip?

Comment: @Joseph You mean in a single step? Not that I'm aware off. But why not do the process two times?